# Создание бота для рассылки сообщений в ВК

Tags: вконтакте, бот, рассылка

Есть у меня задача сделать бота для рассылки сообщений в вк, но не совсем обычного.

Нужно чтобы он с моего ВК аккаунта писал в группы забитые в какой-нибудь базе данных. Т.е. в базе данных будут ссылки на группы в которые нужно писать. Бот будет брать оттуда ссылки и писать им **одно** сообщение, после переходить к другой группе и писать им то же самое и тоже одно сообщение. Когда ссылки в БД закончатся, он перестает работать.

Т.е. это не типичный бот, который общается с подписчиками паблика, а он наоборот с моей личной страницы должен писать определенным **группам** от моего имени заданное сообщение.

Первый вопрос заключается в том, реализуемо ли это и второй, что для этого нужно использовать, какой язык, какие либы.

Answer (score 0):

Идея классная, но это называется "спам", а ВКонтакте это **не одобряет**.

Реализовать такой скрипт не сложно, можно практически на любом языке, где есть готовая библиотека для работы с [VK API](https://dev.vk.com/reference) (для python есть [vk](https://vk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) и [vk_api](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)). Но он не заработает, потому что ВКонтакте [ограничила доступ](https://dev.vk.com/reference/roadmap#%D0%9E%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20Messages%20API) к секции messages.

Пожалуйста, используйте API по назначению и не нарушайте [правила ВКонтакте](https://vk.com/terms).

Comment: конечно гениально они придумали, какая разница, я сам буду писать сообщения эти или это будет делать за меня бот…

Comment: Я бы хотел здесь оставить ссылку на поддержку ВКонтакте, где они подробно объясняют про виды спама, но именно сегодня они упали) / Разница на самом деле есть. Сообщество не может написать человеку первым (не считая администрации), сообщество банять быстрее, сообщество не может сам себя добавить в открытую беседу. API для пользователей была создана не для скриптов, а для создания клиент-приложений.